# code to edit jmeter jmx file in html

Tags: html

I am working on a application where want to open Jmeter test plan (.jmx file) in html5 page so that it can be opened/edited in web browser. Please guide me what would be the best approach and technologies to use. I am considering Javascript and JQuery for this purpose.

Any suggestion or guidance will be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check this new tool called [BlocklyJMX](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/) which enables you to edit JMeter file online using the browser.

Comment: This tool saved me! I was using a big base64 input for the input and the jmeter gui always freezed no matter what I did. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @Batselot JMeter GUI should work fine. You can try increasing the heap memory and edit it :)

Comment: I tried that . Could increase my heap memory up to 1.5GB. Also I didn't edit my comment from earlier but BlocklyJMX doesn't seem to work . It works within itself for sure but when trying to open the same test plan I get an error of null somethng( I will edit an comment with the actual error)

Answer (score -1):

My first idea was that something like this a Online XML Editor must exist.

Open this URL and place the File over Load URL
Then work on the XML Nodes and Save later the result over Button Download.

Complete Example here 
http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cbf7710f

The other Idea I had was to load the xml over JQuery as you already mentioned. Then place the content on textbox and edit it. After this copy-paste to a editor and save it.

Use this Example
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/read-and-process-xml-using-jquery-ajax.html

Comment: Hi Gerlando, Thanks for response. Since this is not one time job and has to be part of application,  this does not solve the problem. The ultimate goal to view and edit jmx file in similar to jmeter GUI.